# Proper way to obtain side effects while using the java.io/reader in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm reading lines from a very large text file. The file contains a set of data that I'd like to select specific line numbers from. What I'd like to do is read in a line from the file, if the line is one that I want, conj it to my result, and if it's not, then check the next line. I don't want to store all the lines I've seen in memory so I'd like a way to drop them from the reader line-seq as I read them.

I have a function like this:

```
;; evaluates but doesn't modify the line sequence so continuously adds 
;; the same first line to the result. I would like this exact function 
;; but somehow have it drop the first line of lines at each iteration.
    (defn get-training-data [batch-size batch-num]
      (let [line-numbers (fn that returns vector of random numbers)]
        (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/sample.txt")]
          (let [lines (line-seq rdr) res []]
            (for [i (range (apply max line-numbers))
                  :let [res (conj res (json/read-str (first lines)))]
                  :when (some #{i} line-numbers)]
              res)))))
```

I also have a function like this:

```
;;this works as I want it to, but only with a small file and produces a 
;;stack overflow with a large file
    (defn get-training-data1 [batch-size batch-num]
      (let [line-numbers (fn that returns a vector of random numbers)]
        (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "resources/sample.txt")]
          (let [lines (line-seq rdr)]
            (loop [i 0 f (apply max line-numbers) res [] lines lines]
              (if (> i f)
                res
                (if (some #{i} line-numbers)
                  (recur
                   (inc i)
                   f
                   (conj res (json/read-str (first lines)))
                   (drop 1 lines))
                  (recur
                   (inc i)
                   f
                   res
                   (drop 1 lines)))))))))
```

As I tried to test this, I developed the following simpler cases:

```
;;works
(let [res []]
  (for [i (range 10)
        :let [res (conj res i)]
        :when (odd? i)]
    res)) ;;([1] [3] [5] [7] [9])

;;now an attempt to get the same result but have a side effect each time, 
;;produces null pointer exception.
(let [res []]
  (for [i (range 10)
        :let [res (conj res i)]  
        :when (odd? i)]
    (doall 
     (println i)
     res)))
```

I believe if I could figure out how to produce a side effect within a for, then the first problem about would be resolved because I could just make the side effect to drop the first line of the reader's line sequence.

Do you guys have any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

map and filter will do this nicely and keep it lazy so you don't store any more in memory than you have to.

```
user> (->> (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader "project.clj")) ;; lazy sequence of lines
           (map vector (range))                              ;; add an index
           (filter #(#{1 3 7 9} (first %)))                  ;; filter by index
           (map second ))                                    ;; drop the index

("  :description \"API server for Yummly mobile app(s)\"" 
 "[com.project/example \"1.4.8-SNAPSHOT\"]" 
 "                 [org.clojure/tools.cli \"0.2\.4\"]" 
 "                 [clojurewerkz/mailer \"1.0.0-alpha3\"]")
```

Comment: I remember someone pointing out a better function for adding indexes to a sequence, anyone remember what that was?

Comment: Maybe you want `map-indexed`?